# Will potassium permanganate react with ferric chloride?

Tags: redox, solutions, titration

I came across a question :

> Which of the following compound does not decolourise an acidified solution of $\ce{KMnO4}$?

Answer was:

> $\ce{FeCl3}$

After doing a bit of research I found that $\ce{KMnO4}$ oxidises $\ce{HCl}$ to $\ce{Cl2}$.
I doubt whether $\ce{KMnO4}$ would also oxidise chloride ions in case of acidified solution of $\ce{FeCl3}$.

I know that the ferric ion cannot be oxidised further.

Comment: Are you sure that "[you] know iron cannot be oxidised further"? Ferrate (IV), Ferrate (V) and Ferrate (VI) oxidation states exist even though the (VI) is the most encountered among the three. $FeCl_3$ has iron (III).

Comment: Have you considered ferric chlorocomplexes ?

Comment: @Kav how likely is it that $\ce{Fe(III)}$ can be oxidized further ? Will it do under normal conditions with $\ce{KMnO4}$ or do you require drastic conditions ?

Comment: Iron can be oxidized further, but **not** by KMnO4.

Comment: @Kav ...Actually the conditions are normal as the book has not dealt with complexes yet.

Comment: If it reacts with chloride ions of HCl then why not chloride ions of FeCl3?

Comment: @Curious.SWARNIM complexes were mentioned by Poutnik.....

Comment: @Ashish your content of answer suggests that I meant ferrates will be formed when I was suggest show their existences

Comment: @IvanNeretin how do you know in this reaction condition. The OP was thinking," if MnO4- can oxidize the chloride ion in HCl, can it also oxidize Cl- of FeCl3, can't it?" The OP's sentences of reasoning was promoting thought by analogy while yours is stating the chloride cannot be oxidized. So yours need a support.

Comment: @Kav I never said a thing about chloride.

Comment: @IvanNeretin my sorry about the chloride (better quote next time) but yours is stating KMnO4 cannot oxidize Fe. I guess my comparison still holds. To your benefit, the OP narrowed the scope of the question in stating the OP knows the $\ce{Fe^3+}$ cannot be oxidized further.

Comment: @Kav Well, ferrates are stronger oxidants than permanganates, and other higher oxidation states of Fe don't exist in water.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thank you for helping out.

Comment: [Bleach can oxidize a Fe(III) salt to Fe(VI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_ferrate)

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh ..I am talking about KMnO4 being the oxidising agent not bleach.

Comment: Did you not read Ivan's comment: "Iron can be oxidized further, but not by KMnO4". KMnO4 can't but bleach can.

Comment: @Curious.SWARNIM What were the other compounds given?

Comment: @Rishi ..the other options are:SO2,H2O2,FeSO4